# JMS and "transactional messages"

Tags: java, jms

I'm new to JMS and would appreciate your help.

Everything I read about JMS gives me the impression that the object that "holds a transaction" is a session object, meaning that when we "session.commit()", everything that has happened since last commit is settled.

My question regards, how to handle the patter where I want to "transact messages", not the session. Imagine that you want to receive a large number of trades in a very concurrent scenario, and upon receiving any individual message and processing you'd like to "message.commit()". How can we implement this scenario ?
Would I have to keep creating QueueSessions for every message that I wanted to dequeue ? Isn't there too much overhead ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, a JMS Session object is responsible for managing transactions. The Session.Commit() call commits all messages received/sent in that session. Similarly the Session.Rollback() rolls back messages in a session.

For your requirement you can use a non-transacted session with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE option. Like:

```
createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

A CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE session let's you do a message.Acknowledge which tells the messaging provider to remove that message from queue/topic.

But you have to keep in mind that the implementation of message.Acknowledge is implementation dependent. Some messaging providers allow per message acknowledge where as others do a acknowledge all messages. In per message acknowledge, only the message on which acknowledge is called, will be removed from messaging provider. All other messages received and not acknowledged will not be removed. Where as in the 'acknowledge all' type of implementation, calling acknowledge on one message will acknowledge all messages received before. This is same as doing a session.commit in a transacted session.